# Algorithm for forming groups that has different capacities, based on people's choice | Challenging

Tags: algorithm

Here is the real life problem:
There are limited amount of rooms that are different capacities (for example, 20 rooms in total: 6 rooms of 4 person, 4 rooms of 5 person, 7 rooms of 3 person, 3 rooms of 2 person).

There are 5 different grade of student. Let's say Grade 1,2,3,4,5. Students from different grades can't be in the same room.

Each student writes down students he wants to stay with. Each students has to write down #max capacity of room - 1 (in our example, max capacity of a room is 5, so each has to write down 4 students)

Each students writes down 1 student they don't want to stay with.

What can be the best algorithm for making the rooms, as much as preferred it can possibly be?

Thanks in advance all those who will reply.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that's well suited to [constraint programming](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver). You need to be a lot more precise about what "preferred" means though.

Comment: So the students know ahead of time what the capacity of their room is? Or, if not, how do you deal with excess or insufficient names?